# How to get POSIX Timezone with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, timezone, posix

I have to get Timezone in this format:

```
"CET-01:00:00CEST-02:00:00,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00"
```

How to achive this?

Comment: Are you asking for the system's current time zone?  Or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout Boost timezone example [Flight Time Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.flight)

to simple things up, load DB file ("date_time_zonespec.csv").
Then you can query for posix timezone string using:

```
time_zone_ptr nyc_tz = tz_db.time_zone_from_region("America/New_York");
```

The boost timezone db file can be found here: [link (Raw -> save file as)](https://github.com/boost-vault/date_time/blob/master/date_time_zonespec.csv)